# Nautilus renames home folder Home, how to stop this?

Tags: nautilus

The Nautilus in Ubuntu 11.10 displays Home as the name of the user's home folder, the folder isn't really called Home, it's probably called /home/username.

I want to see the REAL name in nautilus, how can I do this?

I've tried Ubuntu-Tweak, Dconf, Gconf, and Gnome-Settings(advanced Settings), but no luck.

Answer (score 2):

Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and type:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.nautilus.preferences always-use-location-entry true
```

To revert it type:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.nautilus.preferences always-use-location-entry false
```

Answer (score 1):

You're right, it does do that and does it consistently as an entity. I don't think that's configurable. But I do think it's quite appropriate, because that folder is actually called Home. For instance, if you're running commands in your terminal, then you'll refer to it as $HOME or even just ~, which is a shortcut to $HOME.

There is no rule that a users home directory is in /home. For instance, in a shared environment, then users might have their homes in /home/business_a/salesdepartment/username/. If such a user was to refer to his home directory, he'd still use $HOME. Or a more practical example is root. If you press alt+f2 and run nautilus, you'll run Nautilus as root. Home would then refer to /root, just as $HOME would refer to /root in a terminal.

So, when you're referring to your own home directory, its name is Home. However, if in Nautilus you press ctrl+L to see the *location*, then it's appropriately displayed as /home/username or wherever your home directory is located because then you're talking about the address of your home.

It would be interesting to know why you would want to change this.

Answer (score 0):

With the exception of the Desktop it simply shows the Name= from the .desktop of whatever app's .window is which currently in focus

The default .desktop for nautilus has a "Name=Home Folder". You can change that to whatever you want but it's only going to show whatever it is, not the current location in nautilus